# Pass state(index) to several children

Tags: reactjs, use-state

After learning how to pass a state to a child, I am now wondering how to do it between children.

Parent:

```
const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const [isIndex, setIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
        <Slider
          setIndex={isIndex}
          {...data}
        />
        <Views
          setIndex={setIndex}
          {...data}
        />
    </>
  );
};
```

Child1 (Views):

```
const Views = (data) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {data.views.edges.map(({ node: view }, index) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              data.setIndex(index);
            }}
          >
            <p>Hello</p>
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Child2 (Slider):

```
const Slider = (data) => {
  return (
      <Swiper initialSlide={data.isIndex}>
        {data.views.edges.map(({ node: view }) => (
          <SwiperSlide>Slide</SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
  );
};
```

This returns a rather strange error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.classList')`.

What I would like to do is pass the index of Views to Slider.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Check out the example for "Lifting State Up" in the documentation.  
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: just few tips: when you pass properties to a component, that components recieved properties, not data hence by convention it should be called `props` not `data`. also you cna deconstruct props like so `{setindex, index, etc}` instead of `data`.

Comment: @Tanvir thank you for pointing me into this direction. It is still very complicated for me to understand as a newbie.

Comment: Hey @Tanvir, I'm unable to implement the Lift State. Would you mind being of some (more) help?

Comment: Check the answer section. I tried to explain the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Props:**

- Props are data which is passed to the component when it is added to ReactDOM
- Props are immutable- means component can never change it's own props.

**Data Flow:**

- When two child component have to share/use same data, parent component will pass this data to child component. **Data (as Props) flows from Up to Down**
- Now this data is owned by Parent component. So any change of this data have to handle by this parent component also. For example, if child component wants to change this Data, they have to call parent's component change handler. **Change Event flow from child to parent**.

In your example `PostTemplate` is parent and `Views` & `Slider` are child.

- `PostTemplate` own and manage index data (state).
- `PostTemplate` will send index data (state) to child components: `Views` & `Slider`
- Now both components have index value in their Props.
- Child component `Views` need to change the value of Index. So parent component also pass it's own index change handler to `Views` component
- `Views` component calls the change handler it got from it's parent as props when it needs to change Index value.

Here is a working example from your code in question:

```js
function Slider(props) {
   return (
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Slider Component </legend>
       <p>Got Index data as Props: {props.index}</p>
     </fieldset>);
}

class PostTemplate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setIndex = this.setIndex.bind(this);
    this.state = {index: 0};
  }

  setIndex(e) {
    this.setState({index: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const index = this.state.index;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>PostTemplate Component:</legend>
        <ol>
          <li key={1}> This is parent component which has two child componets: Slider, Views </li>
          <li key={2}> As Index data is used by both of it's child components, Index data is initilized and managed by this component.</li>
          <li key={3}> When a child component needs to use this data (state:index), Posttemplate (parent) will pass the value as props  </li>
          <li key={3}> When a child component needs to change this data (state:index), Posttemplate (parent) will pass the changeHandler as props  </li>
        </ol>
        <Views
           index={index}
           setIndex={this.setIndex}/>
        <Slider
          index={index} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}

function Views(props) {
  return (<fieldset>
            <legend>Views Component </legend>
            <p>Got Index data as Props: {props.index}</p>
            <p>Got index change handler function from Props: {typeof props.setIndex }</p>
            <input
                  value={props.index}
                  onChange={props.setIndex} />
           </fieldset>);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PostTemplate />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js">

<div id="root">
  <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
```

[**Try it on CodePen**](https://codepen.io/tanvir86/pen/mdqoYrx)